# CloudFormation Windows Instances Bootstrapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, domaincontroller

I understand that we need leverage `user-data` to inject any script or code. There are few aspects of automation like - `changing the host-name` or `joining to a domain controller` which would involve restarting of the instance.

Say if I want to do both i.e. change the `host-name` - the instance would perform restart and for the subsequent steps of `domain-join` would be ignored.

Is there a way / work around to get this through ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just run all necesary commands and run 'Restart-Computer'.
Userdata runs only on the initial start of the instance lifecycle so you're fine to do this.